# How come my Button won't change position or move?

Tags: java, jgrasp

I have this code which works, but every time I change the coordinates, it doesn't work! I have tried almost everything (hopefully there is a solution) to fix this, but nothing works. I basically want the `button` to appear next to the `label`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class jframetest 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Not Main");
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

      JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");

      Random generate = new Random();
      Random rand = new Random();

      String[] name = {"Landry", "Azariah", "Oakley", "Lennon", "Charlie", "Skyler", "Dakota", "Armani", "Phoenix" , "Justice", "Casey", "Emory", "Remy", "Emerson", "Amari", "Roxie", "Hayden", "River", "Milan", "Tatum", "Jessie", "Finley", "Riley", "Rowan", "Sage", "Jamie", "Rory", "Harley", "Leighton", "Peyton", "Dallas", "Remington", "Quinn", "Alexis", "Sawyer", "Kamryn", "Parker", "Avery", "Eden", "Lyric", "Elliot", "Reese", "Zion", "Rylan", "Jordan", "Taylor", "Morgan", "Kendall", "Rylee", "Ryan", "Reagan", "Logan", "Hunter", "Carter"};
      String[] images = new String[]{"image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg", "image7.jpg", "image8.jpg", "image9.jpg", "image10.jpg", "image11.jpg", "image12.jpg", "image13.jpg"};

      int index = (int) (Math.random() * (images.length - 1));

      JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(images[index]));
      button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
      button.setBounds(5, 5, 100, 50);

      JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Customer: " + name[generate.nextInt(54)]);
      label2.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 25);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
      frame.getContentPane().add(button);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.pack();
      label.setText("Test");
      frame.add(button);
      frame.add(label);
      frame.add(label2);   
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't focus on the pixel location of the button, but on the flow of user through your interface, then make use of appropriate layout managers. To answer your question, it's because the frame is using a BorderLayout

Answer (score 1):

You could use `FlowLayout` for `JFrame`

```
// this line added
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
frame.add(button);
frame.add(label);
frame.add(label2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I just found online on Oracle which helped me use `BorderLayout`. Here is what I did to get it to work:

```
 frame.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

It works and it does exactly what I want it to do. But what I need now is how to set the size of the button.

Comment: To set the size of a button, simply `buttonObj.setSize(new Dimension(x,y));`